# UWP .appxupload error while uploading to the Windows store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I'm uploading a new `.appxupload` file to the *Windows Store* web portal and it gives error as shown in the screenshot:

[image: UWP .appxupload error to the Windows Store web portal]

I've followed all [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) and my account is associated with developer account.
I've ran Windows App Certification Kit and everything passed.

How do I fix this? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Could you please click Delete button and save button in turn, then go back to the Package page to upload again to see if it works?
Please make sure that you upload the latest .appxupload and remove the previous error packages.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  I tried your suggestions. It didn't work. Further, I tried  individual .appx and .appxupload file for x86 and x64 (to narrow the issue). No luck

Comment: check you your network upload usage through taskmanager while uploading package , it is actually uploading or not. if no upload usage then try again with attaching vpn, because as i can see in screenshot your package is not uploading at all 0 bytes or may be store issue. or also pick mobile if your app can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Using Fiddler logs, it turns out https://upload.xboxlive.com site falls under Games category and blocked by our organization